# mocking and integration testing for managed and sessions beans

Tags: jakarta-ee, junit, mocking, ejb, integration

I don't know what am I doing wrong but I'm really frustrated and in a race with time. I have EJB entities that are derived from database,stateless local session beans (most of them facades) that persists these entities into db and managed beans that use session beans.

So my managed beans look like these:

```
@ManagedBean
public class SomeBean {

   //attributes

    @EJB
    private SomeSessionBean sb;

    // getters and setters and other methods

    public void createObject(){
       // some logic
          sh.method(arguments);
    }
}
```

I need to do some JUnit mock (preferably using Mockito) testing in my managed beans.
I also need to do mock and integration with db testing in my session beans.Also few testings using Arquillian (from what I understood Arquillian integrates tests with the Jboss server)

Can anyone explain or write some sample code, or point to some sites but please let them be relevant to my case?

I'm working in a web application in NetBeans.

Answer (score 1):

Testing your managed beans using JUnit and Mockito is easy if you are use setters for your dependencies. Your example could look like this:

```
@ManagedBean
public class SomeBean {

    private SomeSessionBean sb;

    @EJB 
    public void setSomeSessionBean(SomeSessionBean sb) {
        this.sb = sb;
    }

    public void createObject(Object obj) {
        sb.createObject(obj);
    }
}
```

The test would look like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SomeBeanTest {

    private SomeBean bean;

    @Mock
    private SomeSessionBean sb;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        bean = new SomeBean();
        bean.setSomeSessionBean(sb);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreateObject() throws Exception {
        Object obj = new Object();

        bean.createObject(obj);

        Mockito.verify(sb).createObject(obj);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I init the managed bean in the @Before method of JUnit setting mocks for all dependencies. In the actual test, I use [Mockito.verify](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#verify%28T%29) to verify that `createObject` is called on the session bean.

Comment: Isn't there an alternative way to do such tests instead of providing a setter for each EJB I want to mock?